# Boostrap 3: Navbar Won't Collapse When Clicked Outside of it ON MOBILE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm trying to make a responsive navbar that closes when the user clicks outside of it. 
On my computer everything works the way it's supposed to: when I resize the window, the navbar collapses and the toggle icon shows, and I'm able to open and close the navbar by clicking on the icon, and I'm able to close it by clicking outside of the menu as well (as desired)  thanks to the Javascript.
But when I run the same code on mobile, while the navbar does open and close using the toggle icon, it doesn't collapse when clicked outside of it. So it seems that the JS isn't working here :( Any JS and Jquery I've found elsewhere also tends to mess up my dropdown menu.
Anyone have any ideas what I can do to get the JS to work on mobile? Here's my code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/nikmash/pen/YedEeO) -- if you load it on a mobile device you'll see what I mean (otherwise the code seemingly works fine on computers!)

HTML:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="pull-left navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav-demo" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
           <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Business</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav-demo">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="dropdown">
                 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-suitcase"></i> About <span class="caret"></span></a>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class = "diff"><a href="#"> <i class="far fa-clock"></i> Store Hours</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li class = "diff"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Location & Directions</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li class = "diff"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-car"></i> Parking</a></li>            
                 </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Reviews</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
  </nav>
```

JS:

```
 $(document).click(function (event) {
        var clickover = $(event.target);
        var $navbar = $(".navbar-collapse");               
        var _opened = $navbar.hasClass("in");
        if (_opened === true && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle")) {      
            $navbar.collapse('hide');
        }
        });
```

And my CSS is included on [codepen](https://codepen.io/nikmash/pen/YedEeO). PLEASE HELP if you can, thank you :D

Comment: Have you tried with touchend? like the following:
     $(document).on('touchend click', function(event)

Comment: @RasmusStougaard I did, for some reason that messes up my dropdown menu (like the "about" section).